# Unable to render variable in django template that contains HTML

Tags: html, django

I'm passing down a variable to a django template that contains an html. For example `<strong>example</strong>`. I mark this string as mark_safe() before storing it in my variable.

When I load it into the template and load the page in my browser it shows the html as plain text, `<strong>example</strong>`.

If I look at it in the chrome console the only thing that is different is that the text is surround with parenthesis. So it would look like this, "`<strong>example</strong>`"

Like I said I've read through all the other stackoverflow posts and marked the variables using the {% autoescape off %} tags and I've tried 'safe' tag. These will remove the escaping, but the HTML still doesn't render. Below is the actual html unescaped. I'm wondering if it's the space in front of it?

```
                    &lt;p&gt;Modern Comics That Are Valuable But Often Overlooked and Should Be Sought Out In Dollar Bins and In Your Own Collection&lt;/p&gt;
```

<p><strong><em>Its Like Having $-Ray Vision</em></strong></p>

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: There's really not much code. I'm just loading a character string from a django model. data['description'] = mark_safe(category.description.strip()). Then passing the data object down in when rendering the django template. I reference that variable in them template via {{description|safe}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escaped string first needs to be parsed to HTML. Then you can unescape that string and pass it down and it will be rendered correctly.

```
import html.parser
html_parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
description = html_parser.unescape(category.description)
```